# I don't get correct amount (using HashMap) in Java

Tags: java

I am studying programming and I have a trouble to get the correct amount of products when I try to add 3 same type products. For example:

```
basket.add("milk", 3);
basket.add("milk", 3);
basket.add("milk", 3);
System.out.println("basket price: " + basket.price() +"\n");
```

I get the wrong price because 'amount' doesn't increase to the value 3 since I do:

```
Purchase purchase = new Purchase(product, 1, price);
```

I am not allowed to add additional object instances.
Can you help me to fix my 'add' method to be able to have the correct amount of same type items?

```
public class ShoppingBasket {
    private Map<String, Purchase> basket;    
    public ShoppingBasket() { basket = new HashMap<String, Purchase>(); }    
    public void add(String product, int price) {        
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase(product, 1, price);
        if (basket.containsKey(product)) {
            purchase.increaseAmount();   
            basket.put(product, purchase);               
        } else
            basket.put(product, purchase);        
    }    
    public int price() {
        int price = 0;
        for (Purchase item : basket.values())
            price += item.price();
        return price;
    }
public class Purchase {
    private String product;
    private int amount;
    private int unitPrice;       
    public Purchase(String product, int amount, int unitPrice) { 
        this.product = product;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }            
    public int price() {
        return this.amount * this.unitPrice;
    }     
    public void increaseAmount() {
        this.amount++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At most the 'amount' of the purchase will be 2, because you start with 1, increase it by 1.

The new amount needs to be the old amount plus 1, not 1 plus 1.

I suggest getting the existing purchase, and if it's not there, adding a new purchase for no items.  Then in either case, add 1 for the new item.  No need to keep creating a new purchase every time we want to increase the amount.

```
  purchase = basket.get(product);
  if (purchase == null) {
       purchase = new Purchase(product, 0, price);
       basket.put(product, purchase);
  }
  purchase.increaseAmount();
```